# JMS Message Selector based MessageConsumer.recieve is making the object wait

Tags: jms, ibm-mq

I am trying to create a communications class which will send request to MQ and get response from them.

Following is the code I have written.

```
TextMessage inputMsg = session.createTextMessage(message);
        inputMsg.setJMSReplyTo(responseQueue);
        try {

            connection.start();
            sender.send(inputMsg);
            messageId = inputMsg.getJMSMessageID();
            reciever = session.createConsumer(responseQueue,"JMSMessageID = '"+messageId+"'");
            Message mess=reciever.receive(10000);
            TextMessage outputMsg  = (TextMessage) mess;

            if(outputMsg == null)
                logger.error(" Error while recieving the message");
            else
                replyMsg= outputMsg.getText();
```

This code is giving me the following object wait whenever the code is executed.

```
java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:167)
at com.ibm.mq.jmqi.remote.internal.system.RemoteProxyQueue.proxyMQGET(RemoteProxyQueue.java:2667)
at com.ibm.mq.jmqi.remote.internal.RemoteFAP.jmqiGetMessageWithRecon(RemoteFAP.java:6219)
at com.ibm.mq.jmqi.remote.internal.RemoteFAP.jmqiGetMessage(RemoteFAP.java:6112)
at com.ibm.mq.jmqi.internal.JmqiTools.getMessage(JmqiTools.java:1090)
at com.ibm.mq.jmqi.remote.internal.RemoteFAP.jmqiGet(RemoteFAP.java:6080)
at com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.internal.WMQConsumerShadow.getMsg(WMQConsumerShadow.java:1305)
at com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.internal.WMQSyncConsumerShadow.receiveInternal(WMQSyncConsumerShadow.java:239)
at com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.internal.WMQConsumerShadow.receive(WMQConsumerShadow.java:1058)
at com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.internal.WMQMessageConsumer.receive(WMQMessageConsumer.java:469)
at com.ibm.msg.client.jms.internal.JmsMessageConsumerImpl.receiveInboundMessage(JmsMessageConsumerImpl.java:879)
at com.ibm.msg.client.jms.internal.JmsMessageConsumerImpl.receive(JmsMessageConsumerImpl.java:431)
at com.ibm.mq.jms.MQMessageConsumer.receive(MQMessageConsumer.java:228)
```

But if I change the createConsumer line to,

```
reciever = session.createConsumer(responseQueue,"JMSMessageID = '"+messageId+"'");
```

Problem with the above line is my response messages are getting mixed up during more concurrent requests which lead to session mix up.

Can someone please guide me on how I can resolve this problem?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a small problem with your code. In your `createConsumer`call `JMSMessageID` is being used as selector. This `JMSMessageID`is actually the message id of the that you want to receive. It's not the message id of the request message sent earlier in your code.

You should use the `JMSCorrelId`instead of `JMSMessageID` in your `createConsumer` call.

```
reciever = session.createConsumer(responseQueue,"JMSCorrelId = '"+messageId+"'");
```

And then your server application that is processing request messages must take `JMSMessageID` from the request message and put into the `JMSCorrelId` field and send the response. This way using the `JMSCorrelId` request and response messages are correlated.